# PHP Illegal string offset (error when output single values)

Tags: php, arrays

I have created an array in my functions.php file to be accessed on another page. I then returned the array and called it on a different page. This is what I have:

In my functions.php file I have

```
public function getpostcontent($userid){
    include('db-conx.php');
    $getval = "SELECT `content`,`date` FROM posts WHERE userid = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
    if ($stmt->prepare($getval))
    {
        //$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $userid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($content, $date);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $displayname = getdisplayname($userid);
            $array = [
            "content" => $content,
            "date" => $date,
            ];
        }
        return $array;

    }
}
```

And I access the array on my other page using this.

```
$posts = new getposts();
$returned=$posts->getpostcontent($userid);
foreach($returned as $val)
{
    echo $val['content'];
}
```

I've tried all the solutions I found on google and elsewhere with no luck. It works when I use print_r($val); to retrieve all elements in the array but throws the 'Illegal string offset' when I try to access them individually. Help?

Comment: Can you paste your `print_r($val)` array? Let's see what it looks like.

Comment: You're **reassinging** `$array` to a one-dimensional array in `getpostcontent` loop, so `returned` in your main code will be only one dimension (`$returned['content']` and `$returned['date']`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I can see is that in each iteration of

```
while ($stmt->fetch())
```

it's writing over the variable $array every time and eventually it returns the last array. Change

```
$array
```

to

```
$array[]
```

in order to collect each iteration and so the for loop isn't just iterating the key value pairs of one array.

Comment: Thank you sooo much. I can finally sleep well tonight because of you. You're a life saver. I would upvote this a million times if I could. Thanks again :)